# Accessing individual variables from an object of a different class?

Tags: java, class, oop, methods

I have 3 classes; Person, PersonProgram(the main), and Date. The date class contains 3 variables for day, month, and year. I am trying to create a method in the Person class that returns a string in the format of firstname lastname middle initial day month year. Since firstname, lastname, and middle initial are part of the Person class I have

```
 return String.format("%s %s %s %s %s %s" this.firstname, this.lastname, this.middleinitial ... )
```

After this.middleinitial, is there a syntax I can use to call the individual variables from the Date class for day, month year? I just get "Cant find symbol" with what I have tried so far. Do I need to make another method my Date class that formats the Date in that way, and call that method from my method in Person?

Comment: I'm sorry but what?? Please post **all** the code that gives the error and the **exact** error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if i understand what you want, but try this:

In your Person class:

```
Person(Date date) {
   this.date = date;
}

.
.

return String.format("%s %s %s %s" this.firstname, this.lastname, this.middleinitial, this.date.getFormatDate() )
```

and in your Date class:

```
Date {

.
.

public void getFormatDate() {
   return this.day + "/" + this.month + "/" + this.year;
}

}
```

It would be better to use Calendar and SimpleDateFormat for format your date, instead of a Date class with these variables, but for the current situation, i think this is ok..

I hope this help, abs!

Answer (score 0):

If the date is something about the Person such as birthDate or hireDate, it should another member variable on each instance, just like firstName and lastName.

No need to create your own date class. Use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), the class built into Java 8 and later to represent a date-only without a time-of-day and without a time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.JANUARY , 23 );
```

Then use `DateTimeFormatter` class to generate a String representing its values. That class can even localize automatically.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );
String dateOutput = ld.format( f );
```

If need be, you can indeed extract each piece of a `LocalDate`.

```
int y = ld.getYear();
int m = ld.getMonthValue();
int d = ld.getDayOfMonth();
```

For building such a long piece of text, I would not use `String.format`. Use either concatenation with the `+` operator or the StringBuilder/StringBuffer classes.

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
s.append( fName ).append( " " ).append( dateOutput ) ;
…
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to either make the variables in the Date class public ot to create getters for them.

See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm for getters and setters.

Answer (score -1):

```
Date date = new Date( ... );
return String.format("%s %s %s %s %s %s" this.firstname, this.lastname, this.middleinitial, date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDay() );
```

Comment: This worked thank you. I wasn't calling my getters properly before.